# Advantages and disadvantages of a campaign with 2 unrelated BBEGs active?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques

I have fun ideas for 2 BBEGs and want to use both at the same time. They don't have similar motives nor do they work together.

Would this make the individual BBEGs seem less important? What are the advantages and downsides to having two unrelated BBEGs active at once?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the board. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Currently it is opinion based "Should I do this", a better format would be akin to "What are the downsides and advantages to having two simultaneous but unrelated BBEG?"

Comment: Welcome to the Stack! We're a different sort of forum, ill-equipped for discussion. Were geared towards specific Q&A. Could you add more details about the specific problem you're having trying to run two big bads? Happy Stacking!

Comment: I feel like with a little tweaking, this could easily be answerable using good subjective experiences. It's certainly not a bad question as is. I think the motives of each are fairly important, and whether or not they will be actively working against each other.

Comment: Everyone: Please do not answer in comments.